# Desktop Ubuntu 21.04 fresh Install apache2 public_html 403 Forbidden

Tags: upgrade, 21.04

Something has changed in 21.04. After many years of installing Apache in many versions Ubuntu I ran into this setting up mod userdir for public_html in my home directory.

mod userdir is installed and I ran the following steps:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/userdir.load
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/userdir.conf
sudo chmod -R 750 ~/public_html
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Check http://localhost/~username returns:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: Have read the changelogs to see what changed? Try `sudo journalctl  -b 0 $(type -p apache2)` for information. Look at the Apache2 log files, too

Answer (score 1):

You caused it with that:

```
sudo chmod -R 750 ~/public_html
```

Because Apache switches user to `www-data` from `root` for serving webpages, file permissions are controlled by the third digit (neither user, group, or root).  Files inside `public_html` need to be readable (`4`), and directories need to be executable (+`1` = `5`)

Fix with:

```
chmod -R 755 ~/public_html
```

You shouldn't need the `sudo` here either, as these files should all be owned by the user.

If you want only Apache and not all other users to be able to enter the directory, then also run:

```
chacl u::rwx,u:www-data:r-x,g::r-x,m::r-x,o::--- ~/public_html
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :-)
Previous versions of Ubuntu gave Others read access to a users home folder so www-data had access to public_html in my home directory by default.
21.04 blocks Others access to home directory so I gave Others read access to my home directory and public_html so now no errors loading html and php files in the browser.
Fixed :-)